# INPUT Script with no ScriptSig?

Tags: transactions

Anyone knows what does it mean when there is no ScriptSig under INPUT SCRIPT for a TX?

See here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg19o.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to see the raw transaction, then one could use „decoderawtransaction“ and analyze the details... at least on my iPad the imgur image seems to be blank... no hexcodes visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a witness transaction according to your screenshot (you can see the same missing scriptSig followed by witness [here](https://blockchain.info/tx/eb65976a1b31fbf0690c6a7b0206f9a32669fe91c3427f707fc900b6786a7ca3)).

Segwit encodes the signature information slightly differently from the regular script sig, so it will not show up under that heading. A segwit transaction would still contain the information you would traditionally see in the scriptSig, but in the witness section instead.

Comment: This seems to be the case. Thanks! I also found this website where we can see details regarding segwit trx's [link]https://blockchair.com

blockchain.info is not very segwit friendly.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a P2SH output and the redeem script is OP_TRUE then it's an anyone-can-spend and you don't have to provide anything in the scriptSig

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: @eponymous could you elaborate how it is wrong so I can edit/delete it?

Comment: It's explained in the other answer, it has a witness.